# WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo ideaPad 530. At first I could connect to my network but after a while connection distributed and then in setting it says it couldn't find WiFi adapter.
I tried to reinstall it but it doesn't seem to work.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller [1987:5012] (rev 01)
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
 Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
 Kernel modules: rtwpci
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller [1987:5012] (rev 01)
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Related? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1864509

Answer (score 38):

After 2 days of searching I found the solution.

In fact, if you install Ubuntu and windows 10, your windows system will block your wifi card.

To prevent this, you have to disable the fast boot mode on windows.

this is how : https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

- press the `⊞ Win` + `R` to bring up the Run dialog, type `powercfg.cpl` and hit `Enter`
- Click on the **"Choose what the power buttons do"** - tab
- (If all check boxes are grayed out: click on the `️ Changing settings requires elevated permissions` and enter your admin password)
- Untick the **"Turn on fast startup (recommended)"** check box.

Comment: you might have to turn on the option of fast startup in control panel. the command (in cmd terminal with admin privileges) to do that is "powercfg /hibernate on"

Comment: Thanks man. This one fixed my issue

Comment: Oh thank you so much bro, I have the same issue, I have tried reinstall both window and ubuntu on my laptop, but this issue still happens. Now the wifi card on Ubuntu works well 

Comment: This also was the solution I needed. Thank you!

Comment: 2023 HP Probook dual boot - it works.  Thank you.

Comment: You saved me. You saved my night.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and rectified by doing the following:

1. Go to software and updates
2. Disabled the proprietary wireless lan driver
3. Restart the pc
4. Et voilà!

Comment: How does this help?

Answer (score 5):

I had a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04. WiFi was working during the live session, but I was getting WiFi adapter missing, after the OS installation. I saw many threads and tried few options.

1. If you have access to wired connection, try connecting the Ethernet cable and then update the driver in 'Software & Update' which might fix the issue. If you don't have access to wired connection, you can try by using USB tethering using a phone (Android). Here is a link on how to do USB tethering. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvMZW_ztf14
2. I didn't know about the USB tethering so I tried installing drivers manually from the Ubuntu ISO file. This didn't help me and I just reinstalled my OS and everything was working.

Sorry for the long explanation. Try the first option. It must work.

Comment: I also had a fresh 20.04 installation on a lenovo ideapad and the wifi icon was missing in the top menubar. Installed 22.04 and that fixed it. Not the best solution, but it worked.

Comment: iPhone personal hotspot tethering network works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using a tethering USB as well, but had to run software and update and 'sudo apt-get update' on the terminal for turn on the Wi-Fi. After the update the terminal shows this massage of 'delete not used puglins? ', or something like that, and I typed 'y'. It just worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too (wifi adapter was not found) and I couldn’t connect to Ethernet either to even try the method above. Here’s the solution that worked for me:

1: reboot and on startup if you have 2 OS’s installed on your pc you should see an option that says “advanced options for Ubuntu”

2. Choose that option and revert back to a previous version

After I did that, wifi and Ethernet were working again

Comment: Yes, it works for a short time, but not a long-term solution.

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling with this, too, and none of the other solutions worked. What did work was running:

```sh
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```