# Ubuntu wifi Adapter 20.04 not found

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, broadcom

Hi recently install ubuntu 20.04 and wifi module didn't show in settings.
After doing some updates it is coming up in setting but giving error "NO Adapter found"

I ran the command as suggested in stackoverflow:
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

And I got below :

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]

Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast

Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)

0: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

Can anyone suggest what should I try, I am relatively new to Ubuntu and tried what I found on stackoverflow and other link. Nothing worked for me sofar.

Comment: Maybe this answers your query https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234118/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: No its a temp fix to connect to internet.
I am using dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04.
windows 10 wifi works just fine and prior to ubuntu 20.0,wifi was working with 18.06  .
But now it fails to do so.