# Ubuntu 20.04: Wifi adapter not found

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

My wifi stopped working on my laptop. Running a software update using the updater did not work.

Ubuntu: 20.04.1 TLS

Adapters seem to be enabled.

```
sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:81430000-81433fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: b4:a9:fc:9d:59:fe
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:81304000-81304fff memory:81300000-81303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 4a:bd:98:cd:db:2b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.83 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Reinstalling [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found) did not work.

Does [this one](https://vovaprivalov.medium.com/fixing-problem-with-missing-wifi-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04-dec50879a47e) work in Ubuntu 20.04?

More debug information (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234118/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-20-04)):

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) [8086:0000]
    Kernel modules: wl
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:34e8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [17aa:3852]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Additional Information:**

Usually, I am able to use the F-NUMBER keys, e.g. F1 to turn of the volume. Right now they do not work.

Installed kernels:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image; dkms status
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic               5.4.0-26.30                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic               5.4.0-37.41                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic               5.4.0-39.43                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic               5.4.0-40.44                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic               5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic               5.4.0-45.49                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic               5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic               5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic               5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic               5.4.0-52.57                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic               5.4.0-53.59                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic               5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.4.0.54.57                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.4.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: If it is a dual boot with Windows, disable Windows Fast Stratup Feature.

Comment: It is not a dual boot

Comment: Then boot with a previous kernel using grub. You are doing all wrong. Broadcom is unrelated. You have a kernel problem.

Comment: Realtek solutions are unrelated either.

Comment: Just added additional info

Comment: As I said, boot with another kernel. Your kernel is not properly installed.

Comment: How should I do that? Do you have a tutorial I shoud follow?

Comment: You can use google and fond how to use grub menu.

Comment: In terminal try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` then reboot

Comment: @Pilot6 How do you know that I have a kernel problem? Where do you see that?

Comment: This adapter is supported by an in-tree kernel module. It is not loading. @Jeremy31 comment may help.

Comment: @pilot6 I can't find a match to the PCI ID in linux-next tree.  It might be an issue with motherboard connection

Comment: @Jeremy31 OP is saying that Wi-Fi did work and stopped.

Comment: What kernels are installed?  Please edit the post to include results from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep linux-image; dkms status`

Comment: added it to the description @Jeremy31