# Wireless is not working (does not even appear)

Tags: iwlwifi

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS and I cannot use Wifi, however, I can connect to the internet by ethernet.

I disabled secureboot but it did not work. Here how the settings page looks like:
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWKUa.png)

And this is what I get when I input sudo lshw -C network to the terminal: [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVJZ.png)

Also, nothing appears on Additional Drivers section.

Results of the terminal command "lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3" is:

````
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]

    Kernel modules: wl

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3101] (rev 03)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234118/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-20-04) and then [Another useful reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/)

Comment: the first one did not work, now I'm working on the second one

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ahh! The awesome AX210! Here ya go!https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301607/wifi-intel-ax210ngw-is-not-recognized

Comment: @chili555 thank you very very much:) it finally worked.